# Handling multiple states in Linearstate in Corda

Tags: corda

We have a usecase where we need to have a linearstate as below.

Initiated -> Updated -> Queried -> Resolved -> Accepted -> Settled

We have multiple nodes as signing nodes in Queried, Resolved, Settled states. We need the state to be updated from Queried to Resolved to Accepted if and only if all the involved nodes have had their queries resolved.

Not every node might have a query. So if one of the nodes accepts it, without any queries, it doesn’t mean that other have to accept it. They might have still have a query. How do we handle this state change where each node might have a different say in the same state?

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed in two steps:

- Write the contract logic so that all the involved nodes are required signers
- Write the flow logic so that a node only signs if it doesn't have a query